# deleting single entry from history in zsh -- Terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh

Is there a straight forward way of deleting a single entry from the shell history in the "new" zsh shell?

I know fc does not support this and I can't even figure out where Apple now stashes the history file (to cope with multiple terminal sessions).

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

```
open $HISTFILE && exit
```

which usually opens TextEdit (or another default text editor - depends on your environment) and remove the line (and the last temporary line containing something like `: 1583100426:0;open $HISTFILE && exit`) and save the file ("Save Anyway").

or - if you know some exclusive content of the line (in my example below *PASSWORD*):

```
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
 LC_ALL=C sed -i '' '/PASSWORD/d' $HISTFILE
```

- the first command sets the option to not add commands prepended by spaces in the history file
- the second command (prepended by a space!) removes all lines containing *PASSWORD* from the history file

---

Both commands won't remove unwanted lines in zsh history files in e.g. Time Machine backups!